# why are there references to nonexistent bash-completion files in .bashrc

Tags: bash, debian

I cleaned up my `~/.bashrc` and I found this:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

These paths don't exist and I am pretty sure they never existed before.
I am using Debian btw...
Have the developers forgotten to delete this?

Thanks for you information

Comment: `apt-file search /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` indicates there's such a file in the `bash-completion` package.

Comment: In any case `~/.bashrc` is *your* file, not the system's

Comment: The whole point of that construct is that if the file exists, it should load the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this piece of `bash` shell code does is to source the first file found out of two, but only if the shell's `posix` option is not active.  The two files are presumably providing shell-specific programmable auto-completion support.

On a Debian Linux system, both of the mentioned pathnames are provided by the package `bash-completion`.  If you do not have that package installed, then the shell code will do nothing.

It is the `bash` package on Debian that places that piece of code in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.  It is from `/etc/skel` that a user's initial set of files are copied when a new user account is created, which means that the `.bashrc` file is copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` into `~/.bashrc`, and the code with it.  Once the account is created and the user has access to it, the initial set of files may be deleted or modified by the user, depending on their preferences.

The code exists because the `bash-completion` package might not be installed.  It is, after all, only a *recommended* dependency of the `bash` package on Debian (having been split off from the `bash` package into its own package in 2008).  If the `bash-completion` package is installed, the user presumably wants to use the programmable completion system of the shell, so the files are sourced.  If this is not wanted, consider uninstalling the `bash-completion` package, or, on a multi-user system, delete or comment out the relevant code from `~/.bashrc`.

Relevant Debian bug reports that have influenced the way this code looks:

- [#655071 (2011)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655071), [#655208 (2012)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655208), regarding looking at two separate pathnames.
- [#498474 (2008)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=498474), regarding only sourcing these files if the `posix` option is unset.